# Controller outside ui-view

Tags: angularjs

I want to use a unique controller inside and outside ui-view.
Using ng-inspector I see `<div ui-view>` has another instance of myController, not sure why.

```
<div class="container" ng-controller="myController">
    ::{{_path}}
    <a ng-click="action()">action</a>
    <div ui-view class="view"></div>
</div>
```

---

```
app.controller("myController",function ($scope) {
        $scope.action = function(){
          $scope._path= "changed";
         }
});
```

The result of this issue is if I click on `<button ng-click="action()">action</button>` I see the changes in `_path`, if the same button is inside ui-view, `_path` doesn't changes. How can I make this work?

Answer (score 2):

When you define your state you can specify the controller you want to use inside your view as follows:

```
$stateProvider.state('myState', {
    url: '/my-state',
    templateUrl: '/templates/my-state.html',
    controller: 'myController'
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Can you show me how you are defining your state? Also, is there any special reason for having the controller outside your ui-view?

Comment: ok I figure it out, it was just me getting lost in 4 nested view (one of those had another ng-controller directive).

Comment: Anyway what's the real difference between the use of ng-controller and define the controller in route?

Comment: You may want to have different controllers for each one of your routes. If you have an admin interface with different 'pages', you may want to have one controller for each 'page' rather then having all of them in a single file.